# I do not know how to correctly write this kind of sentence

Tags: punctuation, lists

> A man is selling fruits and there are 3 kinds: apple, banana and melon.

In the above sentence ":" is used, but if I do not want to use ":", how should I write a sentence?

I am thinking of

> A man is selling fruits and there are 3 kinds of apple, banana and melon.

However, I am not sure replacing ":" with "of" is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the `:` with `of` makes it sound like there are 3 kinds of each fruit

You can use comma

> A man is selling 3 kinds of fruits, apple, banana and melon.

or better, semicolon

> A man is selling 3 kinds of fruits; apple, banana and melon.

However a colon is just fine

Many other ways:

> A man is selling 3 kinds of fruits, namely apple, banana and melon.
>   A man is selling 3 kinds of fruits, i.e. apple, banana and melon.

Comment: Do you mean ";" is better than ":" or using ":" is incorrect?

Comment: No colon works fine. But you wanted to not use colon. Replacing it with of is wrong

Comment: Thank you very much. Isn't there any other way to write it correctly than using : or ;?

Comment: *A man is selling 3 kinds of fruit, which are apple, banana, and melon.*

Comment: @James please see updates

Comment: @mplungjan I saw the updates. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Davo Oh, thank you. I use 'which' many times but I couldn't think of using which this time.